# gcloud ingress https redirect define through a helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, https, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubernetes-helm

Now that http to https redirect is implemented in gcloud I am wondering how to define this programmatically in my helm chart template that defines my ingress. See
[google issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733) for the google issue.

Here is one of the tutorials on how to set this up in the console [setting-up-traffic-management](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management). This is straight forward but if it can't be scripted it is not cool. I use helm and I have set up a working ingress with google managed certificate like this:

> templates/ingress-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: managed-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: {{ .Values.static_ip }}
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: {{ .Values.managed-certificates }}
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: {{ .Values.name }}
    servicePort: {{ .Values.backend.port }}
```

That works nicely and I have both http and https access to my service. How do I configure a https redirect rule directly into this ingress definition?

If I simply set up another ingress with the tutorial [setting-up-traffic-management](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management), I get a 'external ip conflict' because I already have the aforementioned ingress service set up through the helm release.

Answer (score 0):

Standard ingress controller in GKE does not support http to https redirection. You can install [NGINX](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) Ingress controller instead.

There is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782987/kubernetes-ingress-ssl-http-https-redirect-not-working-nginx-docker)

Comment: No, it should be possible now, refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733. Just how to define it through a Kubernetes resource/helm template? I am able to create this ingress the klicky way but that does not scale well for a proper GitOps deployment, Maybe I am missing something from the guides that google has provided.

Comment: That feature request is for load balancer instead of GKE ingress. There is currently a feature request dedicated for https redirect in GKE ingress: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141558919

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will take a look at installing an NGINX controller to begin with and follow the feature request.